# How to save string value as Datetime in Mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a column in my mysql database table with datatype as `Datetime`.Now i have a string in my c# code with value as `17/04/2014`.So my question is how can i insert this value into my datetime column .

Please help me..

Comment: can u include your insert statement in question

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper Sir i have updated my post with codes please see it..

Comment: Answers edited check new command text

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example convert date string to datetime using ParseExact method.

if you can guarantee dates will always be in a given format then you can use `ParseExact()`

```
        string dateString, format;  
        DateTime result;
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        format ="dd/MM/yyyy";
         dateString = "17/04/2014";
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

[image]

**EDITED**

Replace your command text with this

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into processeddata_table values(STR_TO_DATE('" + calldate + "','%d-%m-%Y'),'" + calltime + "','" + source + "','" + dialedno + "','" + extension + "','" + trunk + "','" + duration + "','" + toc + "','" + cost + "','" + site + "','" + callstatus + "','" + location + "','" + incomingcallduration + "','" + transfercallduration + "','" + outgoingcallduration + "','" + ringingduration + "','" + confereneceduration + "','" + empid + "','" + Department + "')";
```

Comment: But of overkill for this question. MySQL saves it in its own format anyway?

Comment: @NewAmbition - Not overkill at all.  `DateTime.ParseExact` is very much the preferred way to go from a string to a `DateTime`.  The MySQL Client should take a `DateTime`, not a string.  How MySQL actually stores it isn't relevant, but likely it's in a binary format.

Comment: I prefere `DateTime.ParseExact` Beacause Some region setting have diffrent diffrent datetime format so every time `Convert.Todatetime() ` not work

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper Thank u sir for ur help .One thing that i need to ask is datetime is coming as 4/17/2014 12:00:00 AM  .How can i 12:00:00 Am to 00:00:00 Am

Comment: @Laxman the `result` is coming as  `4/17/2014 12:00:00 AM` ? or your datetime string is `4/17/2014 12:00:00 AM` ?

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper result is coming as 4/17/2014 12:00:00 AM

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper i am getting error "Incorrect datetime value: '4/17/2014 12:00:00 AM' for column 'calldate' at row 1" while inserting into database

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper Sir i need the result in dd/mm/yyyy formate

Comment: @GujjuDeveloper Actually - Yeah - Thanks for the insight! Could change your format string to a constant :)

Answer (score 2):

yon can do like this:

```
string date="17/04/2014";

DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: You should provide a `IFormatProvider`, or use ParseExact. Because if provider is null, the DateTimeFormatInfo for the current culture is used. Which means that `01/02/2014` could be January 2nd or February 1st, and unless you know what current culture is set you don't know if it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scenarios & solutions relates to your question.

Based on input, there are two methods.

```
DateTime strDate = DateTime.Parse("17/04/2014");
```

// for specific format like in your case dd/MM/yyyy:

```
DateTime strDateWithFormat = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate, "dd/MM/yyyy",null);
```